# I can't connect Google Cloud Platform Server with my Node.js based server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to make a World-wide connectable ESP32 Cam project. I found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpIkG9N5-JM
I made everything in this video but i can't connect to my GCP Server. I always get "connection refused" error.
My GCP VM OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5LTS
Node Version: 10.24.1
I opened ports in the OS too.

Comment: What do you see whn you run this [netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN], is your app listening on 65080?

Comment: If you curl locally and it works, maybe firewall issue,  [curl localhost:65080]

Comment: You need to open the firewall rules to access to your server from the internet (ingress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanyL commented while running  this command

> netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

your app  should listen on 65080.

If you curl locally and it works, maybe firewall issue.Run the following command:

> curl localhost:65080

Comment: It doesn't work because im living on middle east and my GCP servers ip's are blocked .